# How can I work out maximum current on a DIY transformer?

Tags: current, transformer, ac

I'm thinking about building a DIY transformer but I don't know how I would calculate the maximum current that the transformer can properly handle. I can't find an answer online because all the search results are for calculating the rated current if you already know the VA/kVA.

I was thinking it may be to do with temperature but I'm not sure. If it is to do with temperature what temperature does the wire have to stay below?

Comment: What's your primary side wire diameter or cross section area? What's the overall transformer size?

Comment: This is a situation where far too little information is known/given.  To calculate *any* transformer parameter, requires calculating *most* of them.  Can't calculate heat due to primary current for example, if primary (wire diameter, length, number of turns) --> resistance is unknown.  Even with a resistance value, the chosen core material/gap/frequency can greatly influence operation.  Transformers have dozens of variables, and each variable affects others.  Suggest researching [how to design transformers](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+design+a+transformer&t=opera&ia=web) or similar.

Comment: @winny Thanks for commenting, I was just asking in general how to work it out for any wire I have, not for a specific one

Comment: @rdtsc Thanks for the info, I will take a look at how to design them more

Comment: In that case, take a look at commercial offerings and you will find a kW/kg ratio which is fairly constant unless you go too low or too high. 4 mm^2/A is a conservative wire rating for transformers of kW-size.

Comment: This could be helpful https://eepower.com/technical-articles/how-to-design-a-transformer-size-and-selection/#

Comment: Generally you design the transformer for the required current and then verify. If you’re just adding a secondary to an existing core and primary you may be able to calculate.

Comment: Gosh darn it, 4 A/mm^2 and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the voltage a transformer can handle is a hard, instantaneous limit controlled by the core saturation, there is no firm current limit as such.

There are two limits to current. One is heating, the other is regulation.

The transformer has a temperature limit, controlled by the softening temperature of the insulation on the wire, or that's used to make the coil formers. At lower power, the transformer will eventually reach thermal equilibrium with the surroundings. The temperature will be a function of how well it's cooled, as well as the electrical heating. This will be quite difficult to calculate and is best measured. A rule of thumb of 3 A/mm<sup>2</sup> current density in the copper will get you into a reasonable ball-park for hobby-sized transformers..

At high power, the transformer's cooling will be irrelevant, and the transformer will heat quickly, and need to be turned off after a short while. The higher the power, the shorter the time. This would be quite easy to calculate given the mass of the windings and figures for the thermal capacity of copper.

Measuring the temperature rise of a transformer's windings is quite easy to do with a DVM. Measure the winding resistance when cold. Run the transformer for a while, then disconnect it and measure the resistance again. Copper has a temperature coefficient of resistance of about 0.4%/C, or 10% for a 25 °C rise.

The transformer will have a voltage drop between no load and some full load, given by the current flowing through the winding resistance. A typical value is 5%, but you can choose a larger or smaller value if it suits your application. This is quite easy to calculate, or measure.

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed to know - much appreciated.

Comment: @redstarbird I've added some more in there about measurement and a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0):

The current limiting factor is the maximum temperature the insulation can stand without melting away. You have to calculate that for the high voltage side as that one has the smaller wire cross section and more length so it has more resistance and is more sensitive to overcurrent.